# Having trouble understanding event handler example in Lit-Element docs

Tags: polymer, lit-element

In the [Lit-Element readme](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element) , why is the variable substitution required for the event handler example:

```
event handler: html`<button on-click="${(e) => this._clickHandler(e)}"></button>`
```

I.e - I don't understand what part of the expression needs to be "replaced" - why can't the event handler just be hard coded, without being wrapped in a dynamic substitution?

Answer (score 3):

Experimentation shows that without [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), the value is interpreted as the value of a [content attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#Content_versus_IDL_attributes), which can *only be strings*.

So, the following [incorrect] HTML:

```
<button id="x" on-click="(e) => console.log(e)"> <!-- DON'T DO THIS -->
```

is equivalent to assigning a string to an `on-click` attribute instead of setting a `click`-event handler:

```
document.getElementById('id').setAttribute('on-click', '(e) => console.log(e)');
```

You can confirm this behavior in this [demo](https://lit-element-example.stackblitz.io) by running `getEventListeners()` on the button.

Comment: Thanks Tony - appreciated. I understand at a high level what you are saying, but I have more questions now, which I'm going to try to answer myself by reading up on a few things, before I bother the community again.